# waypoint.js animate.css set delay or timeout

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, wordpress-theming, jquery-waypoints, animate.css

UPDATED: Figured it out... updated solution which works for each element that becomes visible.

```
$('.effect-fade-ttb').waypoint(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
                $this.addClass('animate-fade-ttb');
        }, $this.data('delay'));
}, {
        offset: '80%',
        triggerOnce: true
});
```

The part that gets animatated has data-delay attr.

```
<div data-delay="500" class="effect-fade-rtl animate animate-fade-rtl">
    <div class="serviceBoxWrapper">
        <div style="background: #000000" class="serviceboxIconHolder">
            <span class="fa fa-glass"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="serviceboxContent">
            <h3>Fade RTL</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to figure out how I can use the data-delay value for setting the delay. As that is being added dynamically based on the shortcode options.

Answer (score 1):

I have have provided you a link with how to integrate the data attribute using jQuery.
http://jsfiddle.net/2Fc8w/4/

**HTML**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
    <div class="animate_me" data-delay="1000">
        Click me
    </div>    
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="animate_me" data-delay="100">
        Click me
    </div>    
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="animate_me" data-delay="500">
        Click me
    </div>    
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
   $(function(){
        $('.animate_me').click(function(){
              delay_speed = $(this).data('delay')
            $(this).delay(delay_speed).animate({'left':'+=40px'})
            $(this).delay(delay_speed).animate({'top':'+=40px'})
        })           
    })
```

**CSS**

```
.box{
    height:40px;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}
.animate_me{
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#00d4d4;
    width:100px;
    height:40px;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:bold;  
    line-height:40px;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

This code should reflect the new JS website

Comment: Thanks but I had already updated my question with the solution. Now I have a different problem as I need to do it for each...

Comment: Yes that is what I am trying to do but different as you can see in my original question as I am not animating with jquery...

Answer (score 0):

Add a css class to hide it

```
.hide {
 opacity :0;
}

$('.effect-fade-ttb').waypoint(function() {
       $(this).addClass('hide');
        var $this = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
                $this.addClass('animate-fade-ttb');
        }, $this.data('delay'));
}, {
        offset: '80%',
        triggerOnce: true
});
```